# I am getting TraceRetrievalException while reading data from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to read a particular data from database. And executing the query to get the result. I am running the code in a while (true) loop so that I am doing the operation again and again.

In some of the iterations, I am getting result but in some cases it shows com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TraceRetrievalException and couldn't get the execution time for the query.
Cassandra version-3.11.4 , Datastax version-3.7

Exception thrown :

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TraceRetrievalException: Unable to retrieve complete query trace for id bf7902b0-5d26-11e9-befd-d97cd54dc732 after 5 tries
    at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryTrace.doFetchTrace(QueryTrace.java:242)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryTrace.maybeFetchTrace(QueryTrace.java:176)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.QueryTrace.getDurationMicros(QueryTrace.java:105)
    at com.cassandra.datastax.DatastaxTestBootstrapper.lambda$0(DatastaxTestBootstrapper.java:227)
    at java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4822)
    at com.cassandra.datastax.DatastaxTestBootstrapper.readData(DatastaxTestBootstrapper.java:227)
    at com.cassandra.datastax.MultipleThread.run(MultipleThread.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any way I can overcome this exception or can I increase the number of  retries to retrieve complete query trace?

```
Statement statement1 = new SimpleStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM keyspace.table where key='405861500500033'").enableTracing();
            ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement1);

            resultSet.getAllExecutionInfo()
                    .forEach(e -> System.out.println("time  :  " + e.getQueryTrace().getDurationMicros()));
```